# For loop showing only the final result

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I have the following PHP query:

```
    <?php
    $row='';
    $access = 0;
    $user = (isset($_POST['nume']) && !empty($_POST['nume'])) ? $_POST['nume'] : "" ;
    $email = (isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : "" ;
    $telefon = (isset($_POST['telefon']) && !empty($_POST['telefon'])) ? $_POST['telefon'] : "" ;
    $cnp = (isset($_POST['cnp']) && !empty($_POST['cnp'])) ? $_POST['cnp'] : "" ;
    $serieci = (isset($_POST['serieci']) && !empty($_POST['serieci'])) ? $_POST['serieci'] : "" ;
    $mesaj = (isset($_POST['mesaj']) && !empty($_POST['mesaj'])) ? $_POST['mesaj'] : "" ;
    $email_status=1;

    $db = pg_connect("host=local port=5432 dbname=login_robinson user=robinson password=123");
    $query = "INSERT INTO tcheckin(nume,email,telefon,cnp,serieci,mesaj) VALUES ('$user','$email','$telefon','$cnp','$serieci','$mesaj')";
    $result = pg_query($query);
    $test=$_SESSION[PRE.'nume'];
    $test1=$_SESSION[PRE.'uid'];
?>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,700,900|Rubik:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">


        <title>Efectueaza check-in</title>
        <?php
            include('include/links.php');
            include('include/scripts.php');
        ?>

    </head>
    <?php
    $i=1;
    $conn = pg_connect("host=local port=5432 dbname=login_robinson user=robinson password=123");
    $test1=$_SESSION[PRE.'uid'];
    $result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT nume FROM tregister WHERE id = '$test1'");
    if (!$result) {
        echo "An error occurred.\n";
        exit;
    }
    $row = pg_fetch_row($result);

    $result1 = pg_query($conn, "SELECT nr_camere FROM tregister WHERE nume = '$user'");
    if (!$result1) {
        echo "An error occurred.\n";
        exit;
    }

    $camere = pg_fetch_row($result1);
    echo $row[0];

    for($i=1; $i<$camere[0]; $i++){
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

                echo "<script>
         alert('Check-in efectuat cu success! Daca ai rezervat mai multe camere te rog sa completezi si check-in-ul pentru celelalte camere.');
         window.location.href='acasa';
         </script>";
                echo "<script>
         alert('S-a produs o eroare! Te rog mai verifica odata formularul!');
         </script>";
    }

}

    ?>
    <body style="display: block !important;" ng-cloak="" ng-class="{ 'layout-fixed' : app.layout.isFixed, 'layout-boxed' : app.layout.isBoxed, 'layout-dock' : app.layout.isDocked, 'layout-material': app.layout.isMaterial, 'aside-offscreen' : app.sidebar.isOffscreen, 'aside-mini' : app.sidebar.isMini, 'aside-right' : app.sidebar.isRight, 'footer-hidden': app.footer.hidden, 'in-app': !$state.includes('page')}">

        <div class="animated fadeOutZoom">
            <div class="container container-sm animated fadeInDown">
                <div class="app-view-header">Bine ai venit, <?php echo $row[0]; ?>!</div>
                <div class="center-block mt-xl">

                    <div class="panel">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p class="pv text-bold">Check-in pentru camera cu numarul <?php echo $i; ?></p>
                            <form action="#" method="post">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                        <label for="nume">Nume</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="text " value=" <?php echo $row[0]; ?>" class="form-control " name="nume" disabled="disabled">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                        <label for="telefon">Telefon</label>
                                        <input type="phone" id="telefon " class="form-control " name="telefon" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                                        <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control " name="email" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                        <label for="cnp">CNP</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="text " class="form-control "name="cnp" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                        <label for="serie">Serie de buletin</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="text " class="form-control " name="serieci" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                        <label for="message">Scrie un mesaj *Optional</label>
                                        <textarea name="mesaj" id="message" class="form-control " cols="5" rows="4"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Rezerva acum" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

        <script>

        $('#arrival_date, #departure_date').datepicker({format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'});


        </script>


    </body>

    </html>
<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

What I want to do it's to see a page for a number of times. For example, if a user selected 4 rooms, I need make the check-in process 4 times, once for each room, I tried with a for loop but it's showing only the final result..what can I do? It's a little bit weird, I tried also with a while but still doesn't work..

Comment: _Not executing_? Do you mean the for loop or the whole script?

Comment: You seem to be running `window.location.href = 'something';` a number of times, and appearing surprised when only the last one applies... What did you expect, for it to go through them in order? Once the page unloads there's no way for your script to control it further.

Comment: It is executing but it's showing only the final result, not step by step